# how to create a layout in which any widget is not clickable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, android-cardview

```
cardEdu.setClickable(false);
```

I have created a card view and I want to show it only for display but not clickable.I have edit texts in it which are not clickable.any solution. set clickable doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your complete block of code for Card layout in xml?

Comment: the code is very long.

Comment: if u have any solution please tell me.

Comment: cant help you like this, without knowing what have you done, i cant suggest anything

Comment: do you have any suggestion how to disable a layout and make its widgets not clickable in any case?

Comment: for very basic, you can `setclickable(false)` to every chlid layout

Comment: i got another solution as well, its by programatically

Answer (score 0):

on its parent view, add setCLickable="true" and setFocusable"true"... see if that intercepts the click event.